# A C# syntax question

Tags: c#, syntax

I am currently teaching myself c# but am confused by the following syntax:

```
new Deck( new Card[] {} )
```

where the Deck constructor looks like this:

```
public Deck(IEnumerable<Card> initialCards)
```

what does the `{}` bit mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an [array initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(VS.71).aspx), and in this instance initializes an empty array.

It can also be used as follows:

```
int[] bling = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

or

```
int[] bling = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a collection initializer, can be used as follows

```
new Card[] {
    new Card(),
    new Card(),
    new Card()
};
```

To initilise an array of cards of length 3 containing three card objects. As you have it, it will be an empty array.

Comment: I think the term is [array initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573%28VS.71%29.aspx).  [Collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) work by calling `Add`, which doesn't make sense for an array.

Answer (score -5):

It initialize an empty array.If you have a class like this :

```
class student {
    private string name;
    private int age;
}
```

you can initialize this :

```
student a = new student { name = "a", age = 10};
```

Sorry for my mistake above. You can initilize an array of student :

```
student[] students = new student[] {new student {name = "a", age = 10}, new student {name = "b", age = 20 }};
```

Comment: you still have a stray colon.